# Finding matrix in a cell array

Tags: matlab, matrix, find, cell

I have the following cell array

```
a{1, 1} = [1   3];
a{1, 2} = [5  63];
a{2, 2} = [11 11];
```

Now, from `a`, I want to find a matrix which its elements are equal to `[11 11]`

Answer (score 5):

The [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) function can be used to apply an operation to every cell in a cell array. In this case, you can use the function [`isequal`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html) in an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) like so:

```
>> [r,c] = find(cellfun(@(c) isequal(c, [11 11]), a));
>> y = [r c]

y =

     2     2
```

Comment: how can i used function find in to cellfun???

Comment: @Harad: I'm not sure what you're asking. Does my edit address what you want?